# how to clear all radiobuttons on my survey website

Tags: php, html

i am writing a website for a university project but i am stuck. i have tried different things but all seem to fail for some reason.

I want the user to answer all the questions by selecting one of the  radio buttons associated with each question. i test it by using a flag value. if the flag value stay yes, it will be read to a database. after this i want all the radio boxes to be cleared. i keep them checked when there is still some questions unanswered with the following code ( if the user press a submit button and not all answers is answered)

```
<h2>1. Are you Male/Female?</h2>
                        <tr>
                            <td width="25%">
                                <input type="radio" name="q1" <?php if (isset($_POST['q1']) && $_POST['q1'] == "Male") echo "checked";?> value="Male"> Male</input>
                            </td>
                            <td width="25%">
                                <input type="radio" name="q1" <?php if (isset($_POST['q1']) && $_POST['q1'] == "Female") echo "checked";?> value="Female"> Female</input>
```

no matter what i try though it keeps the checked radio boxes checked, is there maybe a better way to keep them checked after form submit ?

strangely enough i tried to copy this php code to my php section at the top and it does not work then so i can not put it in a if else statement to only run as long as there is still unanswered questions). No idea why.

as i am very new to html and php i am completely open to suggestions thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if ($flag_variable){

    $input = array();

    //here you can do your database stuff

}else{

    $input = $_POST;

}
```

After that display your form. If all questions are filled the `$input` variable will be set to empty array and will not print "checked" when the form is displayed. If the flag is false it will print "checked" inside the HTML element.

Also, change in your form `$_POST` to `$input` or anything you want

Hope this will help you.

Comment: so in the code that i added at the top i must exchange it with $input so it will be <input type="radio" name="q1" <?php if (isset($input['q1']) && $input['q1']

Comment: instead of $_POST['q1'] use $input['q1'] - if $input is empty array it will fail and "checked" will not be printed

Comment: It looks like it worked ! thank you very much ! if you have time and dont mind to much, can u brievlely explain what the $_POST does ? as i used it from a example but not sure what it does. thank you in regards

Comment: In very plain words, $_POST, is a reserved variable with a specific function. When you submit an HTML form to the PHP script(using post method), it is saved in a superglobal array called $_POST. Then you can use this array to manipulate the user input.

Comment: okay that makes more sense thank you again, been strugling for days with this! have a great day ! regards from South Africa